# Set automatic visible or collapse on TextBlock in LongListPicker item

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I have LongListPicker with custom DataTemplate. In that DataTemplate I have TextBlock and text is bind to SubItemNames. I have also property SubItemsVisible which is Boolean, and I would like to collapde TextBlock when HasSubItemNames is false.

I've created Converter:

```
public class BoolVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

and add to my XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="StateItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ItemName}" Foreground="#DE000000" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="24"  />
            <Path Data="M-65,106 L169.77,106" Fill="#FF0A0AE4" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding SubItemNames}" Visibility="{ Binding SubItemsVisible , Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}" Foreground="#DE636363" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="16"  />
            <Path Data="M-65,106 L169.77,106" Fill="#FF0A0AE4" Height="3" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

but still I am missing something, because I've got error: The resource "BoolVisibilityConverter" could not be resolved. What should I add to my XAML page?

Comment: did you try adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged also check the Binding its different then what you mentioned in the question. Binding is set to `SubItemsVisible` and you mentioned `HasSubItemNames`

Comment: Yes of course it was my mistake.

Comment: Not sure if it's the same on WP, but generally you'll need to specify your resource like `<*.Resources><namespace:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter"/></*.Resources>`

Comment: Can you post some more `Entity` code. Where you have the actual property declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the static resource called `BoolVisibilityConverter` to referrence it

You can create it in `App.xaml` to be globally visible or in your `Page` `Resources` section

First, add `xmlns` statement:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ConverterNamespace"
```

App.xaml declaration example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Page.xaml declaration example:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converters:BoolVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolVisibilityConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```